# Sending mail with attachmen via mail without chooser

Tags: android, email

I am sending mail via my app with this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"email@example.com"});
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject here");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body text");

Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + file_name+".jpg");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send email..."));
```

This works just fine, but how can I do this without Intent.createChooser and do not let the user choose app for sharing and go directly to Gmail app, assuming each android phone have it.

Comment: are you trying to send mail in back ground/ lke this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2033124

Comment: No, just open Gmail app directly without the chooser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can used the following code to open whatever intent you want eg gmail, facebook, email etc..Simple in the **type** as used in code pass "gmail" if you want to open gmail, pass "face" if u want to open facebook

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
intent.setType("text/html");
List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

if (!resInfo.isEmpty())
{
    for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) 
    {
    if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains(type) || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains(type)) 
    {
            intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, htmlBody);
            intent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);   
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getResources().getString(R.string.share_send_text)));
        }
}
```